# Reading in Excel file with corrupt data using PYTHON

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a table from a .CSV file which should have 5 columns.
But, some rows have corrupt data..making it more than 5 columns.

**How do I reject those rows and continue reading further ?**

*Using

temp = read_table(folder + r'\temp.txt, sep=r'\t')

Just gives an error and stops the program*

I am new to Python...please help
Thanks

Comment: are you sure you want a raw string for the delimiter? can you post your `read_table` function?

Comment: my delimiter is tab....that's how tab is used as a delimiter. The file is corrupted in some places. So, instead of 5 columns, there are 15...i need to reject the rows with more than 5 columns

Answer (score 2):

Look into using Python's [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Without testing the damaged file it is difficult to say if this will do the trick however the csvreader reads a csv file's rows as a list of strings so you could potentially check if the list has 5 elements and proceed that way.

A code example:

```
out = []
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimeter='    ')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 5:
            out.append(row)
```

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with the .lvm format but it seems that it is very similar to csv so it would be worth trying my suggestion. Failing that if you can open the .lvm file in a text editor and paste some sample data here that might help me work it out.

Comment: 13/11/2012 7:31:59 AM t1= 17.1600, c1=-0.00034, s=  0.0000, lat=37 52.9112 S, lon=147 58.2424 E, hms=203149, dmy=121112
13/11/2012 7:32:00 AM t1= 17.1598, c1=-0.00036, s=  0.0000
13/11/2012 7:32:01 AM t1= 17.1598, c1=-0.00034, s=  0.0000, lat=37 52.9111 S, lon=147 58.2423 E, hms=203151, dmy=121112
IT IS SPACE DELIMITED

Comment: What happens when you try my suggestion?

Comment: first, it is not a CSV file...when i use the read function...f = open(folder + r'/FLNTU_RAW_12-11-13_0731_000001.lvm','rb')
ln = f.read().....the row(len) is always 1

Comment: Read my suggestion properly. It doesn't really matter if it is a csv file or not I would still try to use the csv module. Using open() to open the file doesn't work in the same way that using the csv module does.

Comment: From the data you posted it looks like your delimeters are actually commas so in my example where I say reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimeter='    '), replace it with reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

Comment: it runs but no change to file